# La aplicacion se ha detenido, Usando Dart y Flutter en VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo una aplicacion en Flutter y Dart usando como IDE VSCode, esta aplicacion tiene una funcionalidad de mensajeria y los mensajes se envian bien pero cuando se recibe un mensaje, aparece "La aplicacion se ha detenido". Al presionar el boton de enviar lleva al metodo _handleSubmitted, dicho metodo se presenta en el codigo, se cree que la aplicacion se detiene porque catch no captura la excepcion, pero que podria ser?

```
  Future<void> _handleSubmitted(String text) async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      await ControlFirebase.instanace.sendMessageToChat(widget.chatID,
          widget.myID, widget.seleccionUsuarioID, text, messageType);
      await ControlFirebase.instanace.updateChatRequestField(
          widget.seleccionUsuarioID,
          messageType == 'text' ? text : 'text',
          widget.chatID,
          widget.myID,
          widget.seleccionUsuarioID);
      await ControlFirebase.instanace.updateChatRequestField(
          widget.myID,
          messageType == 'text' ? text : 'text',
          widget.chatID,
          widget.myID,
          widget.seleccionUsuarioID);
      _getUnreadMSGCountThenSendMessage();
    } catch (e) {
      _showDialog('Existe un  error en  la Información del usuario');
      _resetTextFieldAndLoading();
    }
  }


  _resetTextFieldAndLoading() {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    _msgTextController.text = '';
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  _showDialog(String msg) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text(msg),
          );
        });
  }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías subir la traza de error (si es que hay) de la consola de VSCode?

Comment: @Sergio Garrido Domínguez, Cuando ejecutamos la aplicación,  abrimos logCat para registros y no hay errores, no sparece ninguno

Comment: @Sergio Garrido Domínguez , Al ejecutar la app, no aparece ningún error

Comment: ¿Y cuando se detiene la aplicación no devuelve nada? @user203613

Comment: @Sergio Garrido Domínguez, no devuelve nada solo se detiene, y lo hace en el momento de que se recibe el mensaje, si se alcanza a recibir pero luego de como de 2 segundos se detiene

Comment: @Sergio Garrido Domínguez , lo que hace el metodo _resetTextFieldAndLoading,  es resetear o limpiar  el campo de texto para escribir el mensaje y poder enviar otro